# Chinese Postman Problem for trees.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Prove the shortest closed walk that includes each edge $G$ at least once is of length $2(n-1).$

**My attempt:** I can see that if we think about a multi-graph by doubling the edges of the tree, then a eulerian circuit exists and hence a closed walk of length $2(n-1)$ exists. However, I cannot see a direct way that would allow me to show that this is a shortest possible walk. The second part of the question asks

> Show how the depth-first algorithm finds a walk of length $2(n-1)$ that includes each edge exactly twice.

I am guessing that maybe there is a connection between these two questions, but as of now, I am not sure. Any hints or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm making some assumptions here:

1. Your graph is a connected tree.
2. Your graph has $n$ vertices.

Now assume that we have a closed walk in this graph. As it is closed, we can consider any point as the starting point, so let's just take the root $r$ of the tree and assume it to have children $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_k$. The path goes from $r$ to, say, $v_1$. Now the only way to go to any of the other $v_i$ from there is to first come back to $v_1$ and then $r$, as there can not be any other path over there. Remember: You are in a tree, there can't be any circles.

So we now know two things, as the above holds true for all children of $r$:

1. All edges going out of $r$ have to be traversed at least twice.
2. The only way to reach any vertex below $v_i$ for some $i$ is to first go through the edge $(r,v_i)$.

Now all that is missing is the fact that $v_i$ itself is the root of a subtree. Then a little induction and voila, you have your proof. :)

Comment: I don't understand how exactly have you shown that it is the shortest walk. What if there is walk that is smaller in length?

Comment: Let's just look at the root $r$ and one of its childen, $v_1$. Do you understand why the edge between $r$ and $v_1$ has to be traversed at least twice in every closed path (once down and once up again)?
If yes, you can repeat the very same argument for every single edge in the graph.

Comment: Because there is no other path for the child to reach the root. Am I right?